# Question on the $\sigma$-Algebra of a Given Probability Space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am trying to understand what a sigma algebra is and I found this really helpful [pdf](https://www.stat.washington.edu/%7Enehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT394_axioms-proba.pdf) online. On the last couple of lines on page 1 though, the author writes: "Any event E is a subset of Ω. Assume that the set of all events are represented
by a particular family of sets over Ω denoted A, i.e. A ⊆ P(Ω)".
Here's my reasoning: We know that E is a set that contains outcomes of our experiment with some specific property. So, it is true that:
$$ \forall x \in Ε \Rightarrow x \in \Omega \ or \ Ε \subseteq \Omega $$
We should expect then the family of all events in Ω to be the set:
$$ A= \{Ζ|Ζ \subseteq \Omega \} $$
as the property $ Z \subseteq Ω $ defines an event. The second side of the equation above is what is called the power set of Ω:
$$ P(Ω)=\{Ζ|Ζ \subseteq Ω \} $$
Therefore:
$ A=P(Ω) $.
Ι don't get why the author writes $ A \subseteq P(Ω) $ which leaves the possibility for A to be a proper subset of $ P(Ω) $. Shouldn't it be strictly $A=P(\Omega)$?

Comment: That's the whole starting point for measure theory: not all subsets are measurable, see e.g. the Banach-Tarski paradox..

Comment: as the comment above says: in general not every subset of a domain is measurable, it depends in the measure. There are measures where $A=P(\Omega)$, but this doen't hold for all measures (neither for all probability measures). To understand why this happen you need to learn some more theory about measure theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author writes this because in general not every set in the $\sigma$-algebra is measurable, that is, can be assigned a probability. Therefore, not all sets in the $\sigma$-algebra can be "lawfully" termed "events".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! What you are saying is really intersting and to be honest i didn't think of that possibility...Can you give any examples where i can't assign a probability to a member of an σ-algebra ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $\Omega$ be the unit ball with the usual volume (divided by the volume of the ball) be the probability measure. Then $\Omega$ has a finite partition where the parts can be moved to make *two balls* of the same size. Hence if all these partitioned subsets were measurable we would have $1+1=1$. This is the Banach-Tarski paradox. And it's only resolution is that not every subset is measurable.